# Swapping left and right mouse button in .NET

Tags: .net, mouse, user32

How do I swap left and right mouse buttons in .NET (preferably C#)? Basically the result should be the same as if the user checked the "Switch primary and secondary buttons" checkbox in the Mouse Properties through the control panel. I'm dealing with Windows XP, in case that makes a difference.

Comment: what do u mean by swapping... do u want to do a system-level swap or a swap for your own application?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use a Windows API call to `SwapMouseButton`:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// ...

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern Int32 SwapMouseButton(Int32 bSwap);

// ...

// Swap it.
SwapMouseButton(1); 

// Back to normal.
SwapMouseButton(0);
```

Comment: thanks. may want to add that you need "using System.Runtime.InteropServices;"

Comment: Whoops; I did indeed neglect to mention that. I'll add it for future reference.

Comment: This works but the state is not saved after user logs out. To have the swap state remembered you have to use Porges's solution with the registry.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;

var key = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Control Panel\\Mouse\\");
var newValue = key.GetValue("SwapMouseButtons");

if (newValue == null) newValue = "1";
else                  newValue = Int32.Parse(newValue) == 1 ? "0" : "1";

key.SetValue("SwapMouseButtons", newValue, RegistryValueKind.String);
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here's a code snippet](http://www.daniweb.com/code/snippet826.html) that does this.