# How does RunDll32 work?

Tags: c, rundll32

How exactly does RunDll32 call a function, without knowing the number/types of arguments that the function can take?

Does it have a built-in compiler or something of the sort?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

RunDll32 is pretty much a thin wrapper that calls [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to load the given DLL, calls [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the function address of the desired function, and then calls the function.

It can't call just any exported function in the DLL, though—it assumes that the function has a very specific function signature of the following:

```
  void CALLBACK
  EntryPoint(HWND hwnd, HINSTANCE hinst, LPSTR lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow);
```

where `CALLBACK` is a macro that expands to the `__stdcall` calling convention.  See [this knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787) for a more detailed description.

If your DLL's function does not have the correct signature or calling convention, lots of badness will ensue.  See [What can go wrong when you mismatch the calling convention?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040115-00/?p=41043) for lots of gory details.  Fortunately (or perhaps unfortunately), [RunDll32 is written in such a way to ameliorate those types of errors](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110909-00/?p=9683), but that still doesn't mean it's a good idea.  **Do not use RunDll32 to call functions that do not have the correct signature**.  It's just a ticking time bomb waiting to go off in the next version of Windows.

Answer (score 3):

It can't call just any function, it can only call function [specifically written to be called](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/164787). Hence, there is no magic.

Comment: SwapMouseButton inside of User32.dll is one example for a function, where "magic" is involved. This kind of magic is explained inside of that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30285986/832220

Comment: I just found SetSuspendState inside of PowrProf.dll serves as another example of this kind of magic. Just try the following command to demonstrate this kind of magic: rundll32.exe PowrProf.dll,SetSuspendState

Comment: LockWorkStation within User32.dll is just another example for functions callable by rundll32.exe. The command line is: rundll32.exe User32.dll, LockWorkStation

Comment: My last example is the function having the ordinal 105 within dwmapi.dll. It invokes the Flip 3D functionality. The command line for that function is: rundll32.exe dwmapi.dll #105