# My Mouse Buttons are swapped due to a cmd command

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt

I accidently did this command in powershell windows 10 and my mouse buttons are swapped.

`rundll32.exe user32.dll,SwapMouseButton`

How to fix it?

I was testing this command like in a youtube shorts. But I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Control Panel  > Mouse

Answer (score 2):

[`SwapMouseButton`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-swapmousebutton) is a native Windows API function that can be called from PowerShell using [P/Invoke](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SwapMouseButton.html).

Add the P/Invoke definition using `Add-Type` and then call the API function, passing `$false` to revert to normal mouse button behavior:

```sh
# Add the P/Invoke API definition
$api = Add-Type -PassThru -Namespace Win32 -Name Win32SwapMouseButton -MemberDefinition @'
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool SwapMouseButton(bool fSwap);
'@

# Call the API to restore normal mouse button behavior
$api::SwapMouseButton($false)
```

Likewise, you can pass `$true` to swap mouse buttons again, without having to resort to the [rundll32 hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806575/how-do-i-use-rundll32-to-swapmousebutton).

Comment: Thank you. Nice simple way to handle this.