# Touch pad click different from mouse?

Tags: c#, windows

Hi does a laptop touch pad left and right click work differently from a mouse?
I have used API call to SwapMouseButton as explained in...
[Stacks how to use SwapMouseButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653911/swapping-left-and-right-mouse-button-in-net)

to successfully swap mouse left and right click but the laptop touch pad ignores the swap.

(Used c# via visual studio on windows 8 and 10, the touch pad is built in Lenovo which has physical left and right keys as well as a pad)